# linq 'group by' selecting a number of entities that match a max criteria

Tags: c#, linq

If I am returning a number of audit records for a number of entities, and I want - in as clean and performant a way as possible to reduce this list to the most recent version of each entity, how can I do this?

eg I have

```
Id, version, data 
1, 1, abc
1, 2, def
1, 3, ghi
2, 1, abc
3, 1, abc 
3, 2, def
```

I want the query to return three row entities, version 3 of ID 1, version 1 of ID 2 and version 2 of ID 3. I don't want to know the max value, I need to be able to actually select the row entities themselves

```
var latestVersions = auditEntries.GroupBy(a => a.id).Select(g => ???)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're heading in the right direction. For each group `g`, you need to order each entity by descending `version`, then take the first entity of each group.

```
var latestVersions = auditEntries.GroupBy(a => a.id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.version).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which is fastest, timing 20000 objects shows about the same time for either method, but I don't like counting on `GroupBy` to preserve order so how about using `Max`:

```
var ans = src.GroupBy(r => r.Id).SelectMany(rg => rg.Where(r => r.version == rg.Max(r2 => r2.version)));
```

If you are using something like LINQ to SQL then looking at the SQL Translation may be more fruitful.

You could also use the `OrderByDescending` on the groups instead of `Max`, but again the timing seems about the same for objects:

```
var ans2 = src.GroupBy(r => r.Id).Select(rg => rg.OrderByDescending(r => r.version).First());
```